# Web API model binding on generic interface type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I have a generic interface that represents query options for entities:

```
public interface IQueryOptions<TEntity> {
    IQueryable<TEntity> Apply(IQueryable<TEntity> query);
}
```

Now I'd like to pass the query options using a query string to a WebApi route, constructing the IQueryOptions with a custom model binder.

(*the IQueryOptions can either be a SortingOptions<> or a PagingOptions<>, depending on the querystring passed to the api*)

#### Api

```
public class DummyController : ApiController {

    // optional parameter - query options are not required
    public void Test([ModelBinder]IQueryOptions<MyEntity> queryOptions = null)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

#### Model Binder

```
public class QueryOptionsModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext...
}
```

#### WebApi config

```
var queryProvider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(IQueryOptions<>), new QueryOptionsModelBinder());
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, queryProvider);
```

I'm currently unable to get it working. The API throws the following error:

```
Cannot create an instance of an interface.
```

... which indicates that my custom model binder never get's called. Doesn't model binding work with generic types? I tried writing my own model binder provider, but this didn't work either.